# Saving and fetching a DateTime via the Entity Framework - both dates differ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime

I have a unit test which carries out the following steps:

1. creates an object and sets one its `DateTime` properties
2. passes this object to a repository method for saving
3. the repository method uses AutoMapper to map the passed object into a DAO
4. the DAO object is then saved using the Entity Framework
5. the ID of the saved entity is returned
6. the unit test method then asks another method on the same repository to return an object with the ID from step 5
7. AutoMapper is used to transfer this retrieved DAO entity to a DTO
8. When the `DateTime` of the returned object is compared with the same property on step 1's object, *occasionally* the `DateTime.Minutes` property differs with the fetched instance being 1 higher. In other words, it was created with `.Minutes= 23`, but was fetched from the data store and was found to have `.Minutes = 24`.

Why?

I should also add that during the DAO<>DTO mapping we set the `DateTime.Kind` to `DateTimeKind.Local`. Could this action really result in the date's value being modified?

Another suspicion I have is that I read somewhere that T-SQL's `datetime2` may introduce rounding differences.

I could understand that there may be a difference if I asked the DB to perform a `NOW()` on the `datetime2` field, but in this situation the date is specified in the first step and should not be mutated thereafter.

How else can I safely test setting a `DateTime` property on an object, saving the object, then fetching the object and asserting that a property has exactly the same `DateTime` as I set at the start?

Comment: What were the original .NET DateTime values that came back one minute off? This sounds like a rounding issue, the time being something along the lines of `12:23:59.999999`. If that's the case one option would be to clear the milliseconds before they are mapped

Comment: I can't find out because the DB is reset each time the tests are run, thus erasing the value in question. The tests are being run almost continuously and unfortunately this problem wasn't investigated before another run was attempted. I too can only think that rounding is the cause of the error but this has happened twice in the past few weeks (hundreds of test runs) on different unit tests, but different unit tests which *both involve calls to the same repository methods*.